# SQL: select rows from table where each element of a column is a matrix?

Tags: python, sql, select

I have a huge table with several columns. Each element in column_H is a little matrix 2x4, with booleans.

I need to SELECT the rows WHERE the 8 boolean elements in column_H, per row, are False.

Is it possible? How?
(I am employing a Python wrapper to SQL)

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using a (blackbox) Python wrapper to SQL    :-S

Comment: What do you mean "8 boolean elements in column_H, per row"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in col_H is a matrix, so I don't have direct access to each boolean but only to the matrix.

Since I am employing a Python wrapper to SQL, I just figured I could try to mix both languages :-S

And now I managed to make it work!
My actual code is:

```
select *
from table 
where    col_H[0,0] == False 
      && col_H[0,1] == False 
      && col_H[1,0] == False 
      && col_H[1,1] == False 
      && col_H[2,0] == False 
      && col_H[2,1] == False 
      && col_H[3,0] == False 
      && col_H[3,1] == False 
;
```

It works perfectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your database supports booleans, then you would just do:

```
select t.*
from t
where not bool1 and not bool2 and not bool3 and not bool4 and
      not bool5 and not bool6 and not bool7 and not bool8;
```

If your values are bit-encoded, then they are not "boolean"s.  It might work to compare:

```
where column_h = 0
```

Comment: It didn't work since it doesn't understand the boolean names.
What I have is:

`select *
from table
where col_H == False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False`
Which obviously is wrong.
Any ideas, please?